# AngularJS ng-repeat unique filter displays only a single result

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON with the following structure:

`array[Hotels]:
    array[Prices]:
        array[rates]:
            rate[i]["net"],`

I mean that every hotel obj has array of Prices, each Price has an array of rates and each rate has a net property.

I want to display `Price[i]rate[0]["net"]` unique prices. Currently I have this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="room in similar.Price | unique: 'room.rates[0].net' ">
    <div>
        <span>€</span> {{room.rates[0].net | currency : "" : 2}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But it displays just a single price for a hotel.

How can I iterate over all the **Prices** and to get unique net price **from all the rates** of this Price? Thank you!

**EDIT**

I have x prices:

```
Price[1]:
    rates[]:
        [0]
        [1]
        [2]
Price[2]:
    rates[]:
        [0]
        [1]
        [2]
        [3]
....
Price[x]:
    rates[]:
        [0]
        [1]
        [2]
        [k]
```

I have to display always rate[0]["net"] price. In the unique property I have to check if the Price[i][rates][0]["net"] is not repeated

Answer (score 2):

You need nested ng-repeat and unique should denote to a property of the object,

```
 <div ng-repeat="room in similar.Price">
    <div ng-repeat "rate in room.rates | unique: 'net'">
        <span>€</span> {{rate.net | currency : "" : 2}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I think I've formulated wring the question. I will edit the question now